# Change Cell BackColor on Cell Edit

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell, onchange, backcolor

I'm trying to change a cell backcolor to white, when it is colored red on editting the cell. I've tried cellvaluechanged and currentcelldirtystatechanged, but the backcolor doesn't change until I leave the cell, whereas I want the cell backcolor to change as I start editing. I'm probably missing something small here, but can't seem to figure it out. The below is what I have been trying, which doesn't work as mentioned above.

```
    Private Sub dgvdefault_cellvaluechanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If dgvdefault.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.BackColor = colorfielderror Then
        dgvdefault.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.BackColor = colorfieldentry
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dgvdefault_currentcelldirtystatechanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If dgvdefault.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = colorfielderror Then
        dgvdefault.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = colorfieldentry
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Probably the events to wire are CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit

Comment: Sorry, I also did try cellbeginedit, but that seemed to change the cell backcolor on entering the cell, not on editing the text.

Comment: Hmm, it *is* the CellValueChanged event that you want.  But Winforms does not know when the user is done editing the value while the focus is still on the cell.  Only when you navigate to another cell can it know that the user is done typing and *actually* changed the value in the cell rather then just type the exact same value again.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thanks Hans for your reply, I manage to get my problem sort of to work with a different method which I found on the internet (which I'm going to open a new question for, because its not working 100% correctly). If I'm unable to get this to work however, I might look into removing focus from the current cell and then returning focus some how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataGridView`'s `EditingControlShowing` event.
In C#, you would have :

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is TextBox)
        ((TextBox)e.Control).TextChanged += TextBoxCell_TextChanged;
}

private void TextBoxCell_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bioukh for your answer, but unfortunately this also changes the cell color on entry and not text change.

Comment: I edited my answer. This could be not exactly what you want but this gives you the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Bioukh for your answer on this question. I'm new to VB.NET and don't have a good understanding of C#, but I'll try to figure out how to get your answer to work in VB.NET. If I can't get it to work, your solution to my other question will do for the time being. Thanks again.